# Помогите найти ошибку в миграции yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть вот такой код:

```
class m160115_201537_insert_data_in_phrases extends Migration
{
    public function exists($table_name, $fields)
    {
        $query = new \yii\db\Query();
        $model = $query
            ->select(["*"])
            ->from($this->db->getTableSchema($table_name)->name)
            ->where($fields)
            ->exists();

        return $model;
    }

    public function save($table_name, $fields, $exists = null)
    {
        if (is_null($exists)) {
            $exists = $fields;
        }

        if ($this->exists($table_name, $exists)) {
            $this->update($table_name, $fields);
        } else {
            $this->insert($table_name, $fields);
        }
    }

    public function up()
    {
        $phrases_array = require Yii::getAlias('@t10s/phrases.php');

        var_dump($phrases_array);

        foreach ($phrases_array as $name => $array) {
            if (count($array) != 3) {
                Console::say("Не все переводы для поля %s были добавлены! Пожалуйста, добавь все переводы!", [$name]);
                return false;
            }
            $this->save('{{%phrases}}', [
                'name' => $name,
                'locale' => 'ru',
                'text' => htmlspecialchars($array[0]),
            ], [
                'name' => $name,
                'locale' => 'ru',
            ]);
            echo $name;
        }
    }

    public function down()
    {
        echo "Для того, чтоб применить новые переводы просто запустите миграцию еще раз\n";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Когда поля в базе нет - все вставляется нормально. Когда же я хочу изменить перевод како-го то поля, то выскакивает ошибка:

> ОШИБКА:  повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности

Если ограничение уникальности убрать, то в базу запишутся столько раз одинаковые значения из первого элемента массива, сколько всего элементов.

Почему так происходит? Как это справить? Как можно проще это реализовать?

Comment: Уникальные значения на то и уникальные, что не должны быть......не уникальными..

Comment: А что вы конкретно хотите исправить? Чтобы были одинаковые значения? Вы уже ответили сами на этот вопрос - убрать неуникальность. Или в случае повторяющегося элемента хотите пропускать итерацию?... зачем при `save()` вы пишите два раза `'name' => $name,
                'locale' => 'ru',` ?

Comment: Исправить - довольно просто, в миграциях не должно быть данных, и уж тем более миграция не должна применяться дважды. Почему проверка фальшивит - не могу сказать.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, я хочу, чтоб если значения с уникальным ключом уже были в базе, то они перезаписывались. Сейчас я не могу их перезаписать, т.к. какая-то логическая ошибка пытается заапдейтить одинаковые данные (вместо разных в каждой итерации) столько раз, сколько итераций. При вставке такой проблемы не возникает. Данные разные в каждой итерации.

`зачем при save() вы пишите два раза` - затем, что я так придумал в своем методе save, указать следующим параметром, какие данные нужно проверить на существование в базе.

Comment: @Etki, почему это в миграциях не должно быть данных? В Yii2 нет другого механизма для вставки данных, кроме миграций. 

Почему миграцию нельзя применять дважды? Я хочу иметь возможность обновить языковые поля столько раз, сколько мне это понадобится. Каждый раз, когда добавятся поля, я хочу их вставить или обновить, если такие поля уже есть, но кто-то решил поменять перевод. И да, фактически миграция будет каждый раз новая, но внутри вполне может быть одинаковой.

Comment: @Razzwan А зачем столько ненужных функций?) Почему бы не воспользоваться стандартной `on duplicate key`?? `$this->dbConnection->createCommand('INSERT INTO `table` (`field1`, `field2`) VALUES ("value1", "value2") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field1 = VALUES(field1);')->execute();` или воспользоваться `batchInsert` с тем же параметром `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`  или уж если на то пошло, просто взять модель `phases` наверняка она есть и сделать проверку сразу.... примерно как тут : http://php-mysql-highload.blogspot.ru/2013/07/yii-insert-on-duplicate-key-update.html .....

Comment: @Etki неправда. что если у меня есть какой-либо модуль, для работы с картой метро, допустим. И там есть дефолтные точки (станции метро). Они по дефолту с миграцией должны залететь. А не заставлять  того, кто пользуется моим модулем вбивать вручную станции метро с их названиями и координатами.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не должны. Миграции занимаются только схемой БД. Начальными значениями занимаются всякие штуки, называемые seed, pre-seed и прочими именами. Миграции применяются один раз и всегда откатываемы, seed идемпотентен и плюет на откаты.

Comment: @Razzwan в PHP его нигде нет и надо делать вручную. Применять нельзя потому, что у них четкая последовательность применений, которая позволяет их откатывать и применять. Вы не можете применить одну и ту же миграцию подряд дважды, потому что вам движок не даст. Откатывать назад сотню-другую для того, чтобы добавить обновленные значения - ну, попробуйте как-нибудь.

Comment: @Etki ну так правильно `Create table` + `Insert` - миграция UP, `Delete rows` + `Drop table` - миграция DOWN. Просто надо уметь правильно писать миграции....миграции не занимаются **ТОЛЬКО** схемами БД... в миграции можно писать ВСЕ ЧТО УГОДНО. вплоть да - "Свари кашу". Главное чтобы на "прикат" был обязательно "откат". а что вы там пишите - хоть порабощение земли - наплевать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вы не можете написать откат на что угодно, если до миграции Х в базе появились следы пользователя. Как вы собираетесь откатывать вышеописанную миграцию, если данные были добавлены/изменены пользователем?

Comment: @Etki я знаю. но вы тоже не правы в рассуждениях о миграции. Как я привел пример с картой метро. Она не будет изменена пользователем - и поэтому можно данные запихать в миграцию. И не правы, что только для манипуляций с БД...... - мы оффтопим делая чат.....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский если я еще раз повторю все вышесказанное и проведу аналогию с хранением SQL-дампов в репозитории - вас это не убедит, да?

Comment: Скорее всего дело в том, что `exists()` проверяет совпадение данных по всем полям, а ключ определен на подмножестве из них. Загляните в описание таблицы и увидите так это или нет. Заодно проверьте, первичный ключ с автоинкрементом или нет.

Comment: @mnv, первичный ключ отдельно. locale + name - это уникальный индекс. Первичный ключ с автоинкриментом, хотя, это postgresql, возможно там нужно явно сиквенс указать? Завтра попробую, возможно в этом дело, курсор не уходит. Но почему тогда вставляются данные?

Comment: @Etki, Вы меня так и не поняли. Я не хочу подряд одну и ту же миграцию создать. Я хочу готовый шаблон миграций, который можно добавить, запустить и все поля обновятся.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, Ваш вариант в теории хорош, но на практике таблица была создана гораААааздо раньше, чем я пытаюсь добавить в нее поля данных. Так что у меня нет возможности ее пересоздать, хотя бы потому, что там уже тысячи записей, которые используются.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, оформите свой ответ - возможно приму. Пока единственный конструктивный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я считаю у вас слишком много манипуляций для совершения такого, в принципе, нехитрого дела.

Если не выходит так, как сейчас есть, можно воспользоваться стандартной вещью от БД: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

**ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** - Если вы указываете `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (новшество в *MySQL 4.1.0*), и производится вставка строки, которая вызывает ошибку дублирующегося первичного (PRIMARY) или уникального (UNIQUE) ключа, то вполняется UPDATE старой строки.

C помощью `createCommand` это делается так:

`Yii::$app->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO {{%table}} (`field1`,` field2`) VALUES ("value1", "value2") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` field1 `= VALUES (`field1`);')->execute();`

,где после `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` можно задать любые поля и любое количество, которые надо перезаписать.

---

Можно воспользоваться методом `batchInsert` (метод для пакетной вставки данных) которую предлагает сам фреймворк ([Описание метода](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#batchInsert%28%29-detail)) с тем же параметром `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
$db = Yii::$app->db;
$sql = $db->queryBuilder->batchInsert($table, $fields, $rows);
$db->createCommand($sql . ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE')->execute();
```

,где `$table` - таблица, `$fields` - имена полей, `$rows` - массив данных

---

Ну и еще один способ, сразу манипулировать моделью. Возможно это не совсем корркетно и таит некоторые подводные камни, но на примете держать можно.

**Пример** (не забываем подключить `namespace` нужной модели):

```
use yii\db\Schema;
use yii\db\Migration;
use common\models\Test;

class m160118_064910_test extends Migration {

    public function up() {
        $user = Test::find()
            ->where(['field1' => 'value1'])
            ->one();

        if(!$user){
            $user = new User;
        }

        $user->attributes=array(
            'field1' => 'value1',
            'field2' => 'text 111',
        );

        $res = $user->save();
    }

    public function down() {
        // some migration here      
    }
}
```

Comment: Модели в миграциях - это беда будет, модели рано или поздно меняются (или вообще удаляются), а миграции старые остаются и при деплое с нуля все ломается. Менять миграции под модели тоже не вариант, там легко могут быть зависимые друг от друга цепочки и нужно проверять все вдоль и поперек. В общем я как-то пришел к выводу, что лучше без моделей...

Comment: @kroder поэтому я не настаиваю на данном пункте и убрал его вниз и написал, что это не совсем корректный способ)) А вообще если модели меняются, то это должно быть отражено в тех миграциях, которые меняют эти самые модели. А так как название миграции должна отражать суть, то надо бы перед мигрированием удостоверится, что эта миграция не связана с другой. В прочем, это тема для большой дискуссии. Но в целом да,  желательно не привязываться к ним

Comment: Для справки, в RoR (RubyOnRails) модели используются в миграциях и это подано в официальной документации, как рекомендуемый метод: [active_record_migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) Так что все больше склоняюсь к свободному использованию моделей в миграциях. И не вижу в этом ничего очень уж плохого. Как вариант, можно продублировать в отдельной папке, скажем `deleted_models` те модели, которые были удалены, но могли использоваться в миграциях. Если миграции требуют какие-то модели, которых уже нет - их можно найти в этой папке.